# Copying embedded file from "assets" to File.applicationStorageDirectory

Tags: apache-flex

I need to copy some images I embedded in the "assets" folder of my project into the File.applicationStorageDirectory location, but I have no idea about how to do it (actually I don't know how to access the embedded file with a File object instance)...

Any suggestions ?

Comment: An embedded file is serialized as a ByteArray, so I suppose you should be able to use [FileStream.writeBytes()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html#writeBytes()) to write it to a file.

Comment: Thank you, but for that purpose I need to create a File object referencing the embedded file, how can I do it ? `new File("???")`

Comment: Just create a new empty file and use FileStream to write to that file. Googling "AIR write file" should yield some relevant results on the topic.

Comment: Yes but my actual problem is how to read the embedded file ? You said it is serialized as a ByteArray, but how do I retrieve this ByteArray from AS code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently embedded assets are not by default serialized to ByteArray as I suggested in the comments. For example an image is serialized into a BitmapAsset class.

```
[Embed(source="sourceImg.png")]
private var MyImage:Class;
```

For this embed you could do:

```
var bmp:BitmapAsset = new MyImage();
```

There are techniques to convert that BitmapAsset into a ByteArray, but there's also an easier way: if you set the type to 'octetstream' in the embed directive, it is serialized to a ByteArrayAsset class immediately, which is a subclass of ByteArray. So you can do:

```
[Embed(source="sourceImg.png", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
private var MyImage:Class;

var bytes:ByteArray = new MyImage();
```

Now all you need to do is write that ByteArray to the disk using FileStream:

```
var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath('targetImage.png');
var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
fs.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
fs.writeBytes(bytes);
fs.close();
```

And that's all there is to it.